# How to change label font in code behind using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I fetched the date into the text fields from db. Now in case of failure, I want to show a label ( inside a panel) font color to red.

I tried like this :

```
if (success)
{
    Panel_Message.Visible = false;                
}
else 
{
    Panel_Message.Visible = true;
    Label_Fail.Visible = true;

    Label_Fail.Text = "Invalid Last Name and Employee Number";
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should help

```
label1_Fail.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

Thanks for the edit lol. Stupid mistake

Answer (score 9):

You would either need to create a CSS Class with the styling you want and then use the `CssClass` property, like this:

```
Label.CssClass = "Class";
```

or if you want in-line styling, then do this:

```
Label.Attributes.Add("style", "font: FONT;");
```

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```
LabelFail.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```